# Spring framework same object on page refresh, how to avoid it

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

This is probably a beginner question, and has to do with how the java serves a website. I come from a PHP background, where for each request  previous state is cleared.

Why is it that when I define a bean, like below, the same object hash is returned on page refresh?

```java
@Bean
public BreadCrumbs breadCrumbs()
{
    List<AssemblerInterface> assemblers = new ArrayList<AssemblerInterface>();
    assemblers.add(new BlogPostAssembler());
    return new BreadCrumbs(new RenderStrategy(), assemblers);
}
```

In my controller:

```java
System.out.println(breadCrumbs.hashCode());
```

On each page request, the same hashcode is returned:

```
817233364
817233364
817233364
817233364
817233364
817233364
817233364
817233364
817233364
817233364
817233364
```

And the state of the Breadcrumbs component accumulates (showing the same items over and over). The question is how do avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @syedAmmar wrote is correct, but not complete.
Making your `breadCrumbs` a prototype is only part of the solution. it means it will be created each time it is called, and not only once.
However, it is not enough since your controller is a singleton, meaning it is created only once, *and calls the breadcrumbs bean only once*. This is why you get different instance on separate controllers, but not on separate calls.

to resolve that, you need your singleton controller to get a different prototype on each request.
One way to do that is using Spring's `ObjectFactory` interface:

```
@Controller
public class SomeController {

  private ObjectFactory<BreadCrumbs> breadCrumbsFactory;

  @Autowired
  public SomeController(ObjectFactory<BreadCrumbs> breadCrumbsFactory) {
    this.breadCrumbsFactory = breadCrumbsFactory;
  }

  public void something() {
    BreadCrumbs breadCrumbs = breadCrumbsFactory.getObject(); // this will give you a different instance on each call
  }
}
```

You can read more about it on [this guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-prototype-bean-into-singleton)

Answer (score 0):

That's Because in spring default scope of the bean is Singleton, So the container creates a single instance of that bean, and all requests for that bean name will return the same object, which is cached. If you want a new instance on every request you need to make the scope *prototype*

```
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public BreadCrumbs breadCrumbs()
{
  List<AssemblerInterface> assemblers = new ArrayList<AssemblerInterface>();
  assemblers.add(new BlogPostAssembler());
  return new BreadCrumbs(new RenderStrategy(), assemblers);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The @Scope("prototype") annotation did not work, still get the same behavior.

Comment: It seems only to work when I define two @Autowired annotations in my controller for the same BreadCrumbs service. For each service, the object is different when using the Scope annotation. On page refresh those objects keep the same different hash. On page refresh the bean method is not even accessed.